# Can not access object data and only show in debugger in Swift/Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, twilio, twilio-api

I'm using Twillio API and I want to access error code, but it is only showing in the debugger.

Also, I checked the definition of error it, it is confirmed to Error.

Method signature is func roomDidDisconnect(room: Room, error: Error?)

Not sure why I cannot access code in error.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to cast as a TCHError?

Comment: `print((error as NSError).code)`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried to cast TCHError with below code:        if let twillioError = error as? TCHError { print(twillioError.code) } - but no luck